# Elevator Animation CSS HTML JS(With Logic)

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to get an elevator animation.

So basically there are 5 floors and whichever floor you click the elevator is suppose to move animated to that floor.

I have tried using keyframes with no success also tried transform:translateY()

But it doesn't work the way I want to. I.E. when I click on the 4th floor the active elevator appears on the third and moves to the 4th something like that.

Later on I am going to need to use promises in order to implement the logic. I.E. The elevator is on the first floor and it gets called to 5th floor. If someone pushes the 3rd floor button before the elevator passes the 3rd floor it needs to stop and then move again to the 5th floor. You know standard logic.

So I would love to hear how should I proceed what should I look into.

*HTML*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="building-elevator">
        <div class="building">
          <div class="floor floor-5">Fifth floor</div>
          <div class="floor floor-4">Fourth floor</div>
          <div class="floor floor-3">Third floor</div>
          <div class="floor floor-2">Second floor</div>
          <div class="floor floor-1">First floor</div>
        </div>
        <div class="elevator">
          <div class="elevator-floor elevator-floor-5"></div>
          <div class="elevator-floor elevator-floor-4"></div>
          <div class="elevator-floor elevator-floor-3"></div>
          <div class="elevator-floor elevator-floor-2"></div>
          <div class="elevator-floor elevator-floor-1 elevator-active"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
*JS*

// Elevator written with promises that will be used to simulate an elevator system.
// The elevator will be able to move up and down, and will be able to stop at floors.
// The elevator will be able to be controlled by a user.
// Whenever a button is pressed, the elevator will move to that floor.
// If multiple buttons are pressed, the elevator will move to the first pressed floor.
// if the elevator is going up and the user presses a button, the elevator will stop at the floor.

const firstFloor = document.querySelector(".elevator-floor-1");
const secondFloor = document.querySelector(".elevator-floor-2");
const thirdFloor = document.querySelector(".elevator-floor-3");
const fourthFloor = document.querySelector(".elevator-floor-4");
const fifthFloor = document.querySelector(".elevator-floor-5");
const allFloors = document.querySelectorAll(".elevator-floor");

const floors = [firstFloor, secondFloor, thirdFloor, fourthFloor, fifthFloor];
const activeFloor = floors.filter((e) =>
  e.classList.contains("elevator-active")
)[0];
function makeActive(floor) {
  allFloors.forEach((el) => el.classList.remove("elevator-active"));
  floor.target.classList.add("elevator-active");
}

floors.forEach((e) => e.addEventListener("click", makeActive));

console.log(activeFloor.classList);
```

*CSS*

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(114, 93, 235);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.building {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(1, 9, 19);
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 20rem;
  height: 30rem;
}

.elevator {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(40, 82, 133);
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 30rem;
}

.building-elevator {
  display: flex;
}

.floor {
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 20%;
}

.floor-1 {
  background-color: rgb(132, 236, 236);
}

.floor-2 {
  background-color: rgb(154, 243, 142);
}
.floor-3 {
  background-color: rgb(156, 163, 163);
}

.floor-4 {
  background-color: rgb(217, 228, 120);
}

.floor-5 {
  background-color: rgb(233, 114, 187);
}

.elevator-floor {
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 20%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.elevator-floor-1 {
  background-color: rgb(233, 114, 187);
}
.elevator-floor-2 {
  background-color: rgb(217, 228, 120);
}
.elevator-floor-3 {
  background-color: rgb(132, 236, 236);
}
.elevator-floor-4 {
  background-color: rgb(154, 243, 142);
}
.elevator-floor-5 {
  background-color: rgb(156, 163, 163);
}

.elevator-active {
  transition: 300ms ease-in;
  background-color: orangered;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far? Where is your starting point in code?

Comment: Hey there thanks for the welcome. Basically I have created an HTML file with the building and the elevator. https://github.com/martun-avagyan/elevator-js.git here is the starter code. I got to the logic part and am stuck now. the floors are clickable and it adds an active class to them making the floor red. But basically I am not sure how to proceed to get the animation correct

Comment: Please put your code so far direct into your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with how to do that.

Comment: Hey there. Added the code to the question sorry for the mess.

Answer (score 0):

You need an element that will move. I adjusted your code to utilize a new `<div class="elevator"></div>` element that can be moved outside of the elevator shaft/floors. From there, get the clicked floor's position from top of document and then move elevator element there via GSAP (or any other way of animating you wish). Example included

```js
// Elevator written with promises that will be used to simulate an elevator system.
// The elevator will be able to move up and down, and will be able to stop at floors.
// The elevator will be able to be controlled by a user.
// Whenever a button is pressed, the elevator will move to that floor.
// If multiple buttons are pressed, the elevator will move to the first pressed floor.
// if the elevator is going up and the user presses a button, the elevator will stop at the floor.

const elevator = document.querySelector(".elevator");
const firstFloor = document.querySelector(".elevator-floor-1");
const secondFloor = document.querySelector(".elevator-floor-2");
const thirdFloor = document.querySelector(".elevator-floor-3");
const fourthFloor = document.querySelector(".elevator-floor-4");
const fifthFloor = document.querySelector(".elevator-floor-5");
const allFloors = document.querySelectorAll(".elevator-floor");

const floors = [firstFloor, secondFloor, thirdFloor, fourthFloor, fifthFloor];
const activeFloor = floors.filter((e) =>
  e.classList.contains("elevator-active")
)[0];

const makeActive = (floor) => {
  allFloors.forEach((el) => el.classList.remove("elevator-active"));
  floor.target.classList.add("elevator-active");
}

floors.forEach((e) => e.addEventListener("click", makeActive));

//
// New JS
//

// Get floor's position from top of document and then move elevator there via GSAP
const moveElevator = (floor) => {
  let topPos = floor.target.getBoundingClientRect().top; //Get floor's position from top
      topPos += window.scrollY; //Adjust for scroll depth
  gsap.to(elevator, {top:topPos, duration:0.3}) //GSAP animation
}
floors.forEach((e) => e.addEventListener("click", moveElevator));
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(114, 93, 235);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.building {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(1, 9, 19);
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 20rem;
  height: 30rem;
}

.elevator-shaft {
position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(40, 82, 133);
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 30rem;
}

.building-elevator {
  display: flex;
}

.floor {
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 20%;
}

.floor-1 {
  background-color: rgb(132, 236, 236);
}

.floor-2 {
  background-color: rgb(154, 243, 142);
}

.floor-3 {
  background-color: rgb(156, 163, 163);
}

.floor-4 {
  background-color: rgb(217, 228, 120);
}

.floor-5 {
  background-color: rgb(233, 114, 187);
}

.elevator-floor {
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 20%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.elevator-floor-1 {
  background-color: rgb(233, 114, 187);
}

.elevator-floor-2 {
  background-color: rgb(217, 228, 120);
}

.elevator-floor-3 {
  background-color: rgb(132, 236, 236);
}

.elevator-floor-4 {
  background-color: rgb(154, 243, 142);
}

.elevator-floor-5 {
  background-color: rgb(156, 163, 163);
}

.elevator {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: orangered;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.10.4/gsap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="building-elevator">
      <div class="building">
        <div class="floor floor-5">Fifth floor</div>
        <div class="floor floor-4">Fourth floor</div>
        <div class="floor floor-3">Third floor</div>
        <div class="floor floor-2">Second floor</div>
        <div class="floor floor-1">First floor</div>
      </div>
      <div class="elevator-shaft">
        <div class="elevator-floor elevator-floor-5"></div>
        <div class="elevator-floor elevator-floor-4"></div>
        <div class="elevator-floor elevator-floor-3"></div>
        <div class="elevator-floor elevator-floor-2"></div>
        <div class="elevator-floor elevator-floor-1"></div>
        <div class="elevator"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably only create a elevator box with absolute position (css) and change the class when you select a specific floor, so there's one class for each floor, some class that add a bottom position for example.
I'm currently creating an elevator myself for a xstate demo, I'll share you the link, maybe it will help.

Mine (react, typescript, xstate) (the logic is almost done, what's missing is some styles)
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-ts-xstate-elevator-pdb2g4